# lftp error (550 The volume is too fragmented to complete this operation)

Tags: ftp, lftp

I wrote a bash script to backup my server every day and then lftp the file to another server.
I get the following error every few days on some of my servers.

This error did not occur on the first file until now, and the first file was sent without any problem. To send the second file, lftp shows this error in debug.

```
    <--- 550 The volume is too fragmented to complete this operation.
    ---- Closing data socket
    ---> QUIT
    ---- Closing control socket
```

```
--- current lftp configuration settings ---
    set ftp:passive-mode true
    set ftp:prefer-epsv false
    set ftp:sync-mode/ftp.idsoftware.com on
    set ftp:sync-mode/ftp.microsoft.com on
    set ftp:sync-mode/sunsolve.sun.com on
    set ftp:use-allo false
    set ftp:use-tvfs true
    set net:limit-rate 62500000:62500000
    set net:timeout 3600
    set xfer:max-redirections 10
```

Comment: This is not very specific and unusual error coming from the *remote server*. It's not lftp/programming issue. It's something that the remote server administrator should look at instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not from lftp, and the server disk that you send your files to is very fragmented
My suggestion is to defragment the drive you want with the Windows Task Scheduler every day and see if you get this problem again.

[image: Automatic disk defragmentation in Windows]

Comment: That's correct, but that only proves that this is not a programming question, does not belong to [so] and should not be answered here.